# Is there a way to set "Origin" header in server? (Nuxt.js)

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I'm developing a Nuxt app that is going to have multiple domains, e.g. example1.com, example2.com, etc (This is handled by nginx)

What is important here, is that the back-end API acts based on the `Origin` header which is sent from the Nuxt app and sends corresponding data based on `Origin`.

In `nuxtServerInit` I'm calling some back-end API to load some data (using `axios`), but the problem is that `Origin` header is not being sent to the back-end. It also does not make sense to set `Origin` manually as `window` is `undefined` in that initial API call.

Here's my `nuxtServerInit` function:

```
async nuxtServerInit(_vuexContext, { $accessor, error }: Context) {
      try {
          const config = await this.$axios.$get('/v1/config/')
          console.log(config)
      } catch (e: any) {
          console.error(e)
        
          return error({ statusCode: 500, message: e.message })
      }
},
```

Now I want to know, is there a way to set the `Origin` header in server?

Is there a workaround for that? Or do you have a better solution for my case?

Comment: Can't the backend check from where is the FE calling?

Comment: How is this possible? The back-end doesn't know the Origin of the request.

Comment: If `https://johndoe.com` sends an HTTP call to some backend, the origin of the request will be `https://johndoe.com` no?

Comment: Can you share the code in your asyncData method?

Comment: @kissu No this is not the case, As I said, I'm sending the request in `nuxtServerInit` so it's called on the server; No `Origin` header is being set in there.

Comment: @NickDawes There's nothing related to the `asyncData` method. I want to set the `Origin` header in `nuxtServerInit` hook, which is called a way before `asyncData`.

Comment: My bad. Can you share your nuxtServerInit method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still set the Origin header manually, without access to the `window`. You’ll find the origin of the original request (eg. example1.com) in the `req` object, which is available in the Nuxt context ([but only on the server side](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/internals-glossary/context/)).

I think you know this already, but calling your API from nuxtServerInit generates a new request on the node side— which doesn’t have an origin header by default. You can grab the correct origin from the original request as above, and stick it in a header on the new request.

I’ll assume your use case lends itself to this approach, and you’ve considered alternatives to spoofing the origin of your node-side request.